How to show a digital keyboard on load a webpage in ios/safari?
While working on a website, I observed that a virtual keyboard fails to surface when an input field on the page gains focus during the page load process. I’m aware that due to Apple’s policy restrictions, this functionality cannot be implemented as they prohibit such actions. However, I’m curious if there’s a workaround or method to override this limitation. Could you provide any insights or suggestions?
UPDATE
The main problem is that after the page is loaded, the digital keybord does not appear on the iphone in the safari browser. The customer needs to click on the input field for the keyboard to appear. On Android devices, the keyboard appears without additional actions on the part of the client.
css code below:
    #inputContainer{
        padding:0px;
        display: flex;
        font-size:28px;
        margin:auto;
        width: 216px; 
        height: 44;
    }
    
    #inputContainer input{
        margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
        display: inline-flex;
        border: 1px solid rgba(156, 150, 127, 0.24);
        width: 32px;
        height: 44px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size:28px;
        caret-color: transparent;
    }
    
    #inputContainer input:nth-child(1){
        border: 1px solid rgba(255, 212, 3, 1);
    }
    
    #inputContainer input:focus { 
        outline: none;
    }
    
    #inputContainer input[disabled] { 
        color: black;
    }

js code below:
const inactiveInputBorderColor = "1px solid rgba(156, 150, 127, 0.24)";
            const activeInputBorderColor = "2px solid rgba(255, 212, 3, 1)";
            const hoverInputBorderColor = "1px solid rgba(255, 212, 3, 1)";
            const inactiveBoxShadow = "none";
            const activeBoxShadow = "0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 154, 3, 0.15)";
            const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#inputContainer input");
            
                        
            inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
                input.dataset.index = index;

                input.addEventListener("click", customClickInput);
                input.addEventListener("paste", customPastOtp);
                input.addEventListener("mouseenter", customEnterHover);
                input.addEventListener("mouseleave", customLeaveHover);
                input.addEventListener("keyup", customEnterAndRemoveOtp);
            });
            
            function submitOtp(){
                let otp = "";
                
                setTimeout(function() {
                    inputs.forEach((input) => {
                        otp += input.value;
                        input.disabled = true;
                        input.classList.add("disabled");
                    });
                }, 5000);

            }
            
            function customPastOtp(e){
                const data = e.clipboardData.getData("text");
                const value = data.split("");
                if(value.length === inputs.length){
                                        
                    inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
                        input.disabled = true;
                        input.value = value[index];
                        input.style.border = inactiveInputBorderColor;
                        input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;
                    });
                    submitOtp();
                } else if(value.length < inputs.length) {
                    
                    inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
                        if(index  < value.length){
                            input.disabled = true;
                            input.value = value[index];
                            input.style.border = inactiveInputBorderColor;
                            input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;
                        } else if(index === value.length){
                            console.log(index);
                            input.style.boxShadow = activeBoxShadow;
                            input.style.border = activeInputBorderColor;
                            input.focus();
                        }
                    });
                    submitOtp();
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            };
            
            function customEnterAndRemoveOtp(e){
                const input = e.target;
                let value = input.value;
                
                if(value.length === inputs.length){
                    inputs.forEach((input, index) => {input.value = value[index];});
                    submitOtp();
                }else if( 1 < value.length && value.length < inputs.length){
                    inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
                        if(index  < value.length){
                            input.disabled = true;
                            input.value = value[index];
                            input.style.border = inactiveInputBorderColor;
                            input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;
                        } else if(index === value.length){
                            console.log(index);
                            input.style.boxShadow = activeBoxShadow;
                            input.style.border = activeInputBorderColor;
                            input.focus();
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    input.value = "";
                    input.value = value ? value[0] : "";                    
                    let fieldIndex = input.dataset.index;
                    
                    if(value.length > 0 && fieldIndex < inputs.length - 1){
                        input.style.border = inactiveInputBorderColor;
                        input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;
                        input.disabled = true;
                        input.nextElementSibling.style.boxShadow = activeBoxShadow;
                        input.nextElementSibling.style.border = activeInputBorderColor;
                        input.nextElementSibling.focus();
                    }else if(value.length > 0 && fieldIndex == inputs.length - 1){
                        input.style.border = inactiveInputBorderColor;
                        input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;
                        submitOtp();
                    }   
                    
                    if (e.key === "Backspace" && fieldIndex > 0){
                        input.style.border = inactiveInputBorderColor;
                        input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;
                        input.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
                        input.previousElementSibling.style.boxShadow = activeBoxShadow;
                        input.previousElementSibling.style.border = activeInputBorderColor;
                        input.previousElementSibling.value = "";
                        input.previousElementSibling.focus();
                    } else if(e.key === "Delete" && fieldIndex > 0){
                        input.style.border = inactiveInputBorderColor;
                        input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;
                        input.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
                        input.previousElementSibling.style.boxShadow = activeBoxShadow;
                        input.previousElementSibling.style.border = activeInputBorderColor;
                        input.previousElementSibling.value = "";
                        input.previousElementSibling.focus();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            function customClickInput(e){
                let valueFlag = 0;
                
                inputs.forEach((input) => {
                    if(valueFlag === 0 && input.value == ""){
                        input.removeEventListener("mouseenter", customEnterHover);
                        input.removeEventListener("mouseleave", customLeaveHover);
                        input.style.border = activeInputBorderColor;
                        input.style.boxShadow = activeBoxShadow;
                        input.focus();
                        valueFlag++;
                    }else{
                        input.removeEventListener("mouseenter", customEnterHover);
                        input.removeEventListener("mouseleave", customLeaveHover);
                        input.style.border = inactiveInputBorderColor; 
                        input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;
                    }
                }); 
            }
            
            function customEnterHover(e){
                const input = e.target;
                let fieldIndex = input.dataset.index;
                
                inputs.forEach((input) => {
                    if(input.dataset.index === fieldIndex){
                        input.style.border = hoverInputBorderColor; 
                        input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;
                    }else{
                        input.style.border = inactiveInputBorderColor;
                        input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;
                    }
                });
            }
            
            function customLeaveHover(e){
                const input = e.target;
                let fieldIndex = input.dataset.index;
                
                inputs.forEach((input) => {
                    input.style.border = inactiveInputBorderColor;
                    input.style.boxShadow = inactiveBoxShadow;      
                });
            }
            
            window.onload = function() {
                document.querySelector("#inputContainer input:nth-child(1)").focus();
                console.log("focused");
            };

html code below:
<body>
    <div id="inputContainer">
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</body>


Have you tried setting focus using JS? Worked for me on iPad IOS 16…

Yes, i tried, but a digital keypad does not appear when the page loads in iphone devices. For android devices everything works as expected.

Are we thinking of different things when saying digital keypad. I see the keyboard coming up on the screen as I’d expect for input of type text. What device and what version OS are you using? Could you make a runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem?

I've added code that generates an input OTP field on a web page. The main problem is that after the page is loaded, the digital keybord does not appear on the iphone in the safari browser. The customer needs to click on the input field for the keyboard to appear. On Android devices, the keyboard appears without additional actions on the part of the client.

I have run your code on iOS and the keyboard appears. Please make the code into a runnable snippet and test it to ensure it shows the problem.

if you are using react js you can use useRef to get refrence of the elemenet value then
use below code to focus your input
  const myRef = useRef(null);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
  inputRef.current?.focus();
  },[])

  // refrence your element with ref
  <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />

